# Plugin with Omnibox suggestion - is it possible to not display search suggestion

Tags: google-chrome

I want to create a plugin with omnibox suggestion. The main problem - if user activated plugin inside omnibox and plugin nothing suggests Chrome adds search rows / history rows that doesn't correspond to plugin. Is it possible to disable this feature?

Comment: Check my answer for similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896461/chrome-omnibox-strange-suggestions/13941623#13941623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot... You can however, try to make a sort of work around that would "hide" the search results brought up by google.