# Chrome omnibox strange suggestions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating plugin for Chrome and I'm trying to use omnibox. Suppose my plugin suggests `abcd`. User types `o ab` (`o` - omnibox keyword) and can select my suggestion and press enter. The next time user types `o ab` Chrome also suggests `chrome-extension://jiplmmiemkpcomooikeeicllpnmnlaia/?q=abcd`. If I'll open it I will see `Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.`. How can I disable this suggestions (`chrome-extension://...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this Chrome omnibox "polution" by adding 5 more suggestions. Because Chrome displays max 5 suggestions, `chrome-extension://jiplmmiemkpcomooikeeicllpnmnlaia/` is not displayed. So in addition to "main" suggestion options I have "secondary" suggestion options like:

1. `:help` - open help page
2. `:open_site` - open plugin's site
3. `:settings` - open settings page
4. ...

Your plugin may have other secondary suggestions. This solution also fixes [search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559826/plugin-with-omnibox-suggestion-is-it-possible-to-not-display-search-suggestion) problem

Answer (score 0):

For every [Omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html) Search, Chrome creates two records for **`Keyword`** and **`Shortcuts`** references as shown here

### Keywords

[image]

### Shortcuts

[image]

because of these, results are shown in Omnibox, while searched. However, you can [delete these](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl) references using [history API()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html) using appropriate [transition type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#transition_types).

#### Example:

```
 // Form URL dynamically and use it here
 chrome.history.deleteUrl({
     "url": "chrome-extension://fpcmfnhmjahllmhohkeaempoejojhlln/?q=hi"
 }, function () {
     //Call Back
     console.log("Deleted");
 });
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: 1. How can I delete history entry by transition type? 2. I'm trying to delete entry by url but it doesn't work - it still suggests me. 3. Can I prohibit history entry generation for my plugin?

Comment: @fedor.belov:You can delete all browser history in all combinations,because it is in Sql lite format. If you are on windows 7 you can find DB at `"C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\"`